# JS: Left side of logical OR is ignored

Tags: javascript

I have the following bit of code. The intention is to read a `package.json` file to figure out the output module type if the `format` option is not passed. If the option is provided, it needs to be respected above all else.

```
const format =
  options.format ||
  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
      ? 'es'
      : 'cjs'

console.log(`Option Format: ${options.format}`) 
console.log(`Build Format: ${format}`)
```

So this is the code. This seems entirely simple to me, and yet, the left hand side is ignored. My console logs look the following when `format` has been set to CJS while the package has `"type": "module"` set:

```
Option Format: cjs
Build Format: es
```

I'm quite lost, and don't understand why this is. `options.format` is clearly not a falsy value, being 'cjs`, so why does the statement not end right there? Turning this into a quick ternary works, but is a lot more verbose than needed surely?

```
const format = options.format
  ? options.format
  : JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
      ? 'es'
      : 'cjs'
```

Comment: You're frankly trying to do too much in a single statement that makes this harder to read and understand. In the sense just because ternary exist doesn't mean you *have* to use them. You can always just do `if(options.format) { ... }`

Comment: I don't have to use them but using an `if` extends this over more lines which is undesirable in a tool that needs to carefully watch it's build size. `if` is almost certainly a poor choice.

Comment: There is a reason why minification tools exist. Trying to make things overly complex and reduce lines just to reduce them at the cost of readability is a terrible coding practice and development team members certainly won't appreciate trying to decipher bad code.

Comment: Those minification tools are never as good as an author. The goal here isn't "to make things overly complex", it's to minify and reduce perf hits from hitting the file system. Do I really need to point out the incredibly popular tools like [Preact](https://preactjs.com) which are entirely based around their fame for minification? Saying that writing minified code "is a terrible coding practice" and that teammates won't appreciate it is as ignorant as it gets to reality. Some of us have to write code that fits in tight byte counts. Don't lecture to me because you don't agree with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `||` has higher operator precedence (6) than the conditional operator (4). So the two initial expressions you have (the `options.format` and JSON.parse`) get grouped together first:

```
const format =
  options.format ||
  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
      ? 'es'
      : 'cjs'
```

is equivalent to

```
const format =
  (
    options.format ||
    JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
  )
      ? 'es'
      : 'cjs'
```

To fix it, just group what comes after `options.format` in parentheses:

```
const format =
  options.format || (
    JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
        ? 'es'
        : 'cjs'
  );
```

You might consider extracting the package module in a standalone statement beforehand though, it might be more readable:

```
const packageFormat = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
  ? 'es'
  : 'cjs'
const format = options.format || packageFormat;
```

Or retrieve it lazily:

```
const getPackageFormat = () => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('package.json'), 'utf-8')).type === 'module'
  ? 'es'
  : 'cjs'
const format = options.format || getPackageFormat();
```

Comment: I imagine he's sacrificing readability for whatever performance. He wants to do `fs.readFileSync` only if needed

Comment: Oh gosh, yep, that works perfectly! Thank you so much. It is indeed in 1 statement to reduce perf hit of file system access as well as keeping the built size down.

Comment: @Devildude4427 I think you should google the term "premature optimisation". A one-liner isn't necessarily faster than a two-liner, but it is almost always less readable.

Comment: @Shadow You're assuming that this is premature. It's not. Number of lines have nothing do with speed, though jumping into the filesystem does. We need to reduce that. Furthermore inlining keeps byte count down, which is incredibly important for my need. Don't just assume that I'm doing this blindly. That's foolish.

Comment: @Devildude4427 I'm glad to hear you say so - a lot of people will just jump in to these sorts of optimisations without actually measuring. Blind assumptions are the worst way to optimise, as I'm sure you already know. Optimising for byte count is usually the job for minifiers rather than developers, but if you've done the measuring and know what you need - then by all means, plough ahead.